# Swift SpriteKit iOS - Collisions: didBeginContact for one sprite, and not for others

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I need to be able to run didBeginContact() for one sprite, but for the other, don't run it (but still collide with it).
Here's what I have so far:

```
enum ColliderType: UInt32 {
   case Player = 1
   case Wall = 2
   case ScreenBoundary = 3
}
```

**Screen Boundaries (I don't want this to run didBeginContact())**

```
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.ScreenBoundary.rawValue
    self.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Player.rawValue
```

**Player (Run didBeginContact() if colliding with ColliderType.Wall)**

```
    player!.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Player.rawValue
    player!.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Wall.rawValue
    player!.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Wall.rawValue
```

**Walls (Run didBeginContact() if colliding with ColliderType.Player)**

```
    wallSprite.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Wall.rawValue
    wallSprite.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Player.rawValue
    wallSprite.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Player.rawValue
```

Hope that makes sense, because it SpriteKit collisions don't for me.
Thanks!
Toby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should do is add a condition in your didBeginContact() method, in your case, you should add the following to check:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let other = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Player.rawValue ? contact.bodyB : contact.bodyA

    switch other.categoryBitMask {
    case ColliderType.ScreenBoundary.rawValue:
        println("Hit Screen!")
    case ColliderType.Wall.rawValue:
        println("Hit Wall!")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, just had to edit a few things for it to be compatible with my script.